# Calling a Macro in Word Com Addin on msocontrolbutton.onaction

Tags: vba, ms-word, contextmenu, popupmenu, office-addins

I am developing a com Add In For Word 2007.

I am trying to create a popup menu and each control button in that is calling a macro present inside the same ThisAddin Class.

But in word when i click on the control button in popup menu  i get the following error :

"The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your macro
security settings"

I have tried a lot of search but unable to get any related info. so i think it might not be a issue at all or not a feature at all.

The code for menu generation is as below :

```
cbrCmdBar = MyWordAddIn.Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:="MyPopup", Position:=Office.MsoBarPosition.msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)

            With cbrCmdBar.Controls
                With .Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton)
                    .Caption = "Point"
                    .OnAction = "StopPoint"
                    .FaceId =  70
                End With
            End With
```

And the macro is :

```
Public Sub StopPoint()
    MsgBox("Popup Control Button Selected")
End Sub
```

On the other hand , if i put the macro in template of the ActiveDocument It works fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Below FaceID, add:

.OnAction = "=StopPoint()"